# Rust library linking error: undefined reference to function in divxc3

Tags: rust, ld, static-linking

I am trying to use a rust library in an embedded ARM C project. When I try and link the .a file I get this error:

```
arm-none-eabi-ld:
rust-lib.a(divxc3.o): In function `__divxc3':
/checkout/src/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/divxc3.c:23: undefined reference to `fmaxl'
/checkout/src/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/divxc3.c:23: undefined reference to `logbl'
/checkout/src/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/divxc3.c:26: undefined reference to `scalbnl'
/checkout/src/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/divxc3.c:27: undefined reference to `scalbnl'
/checkout/src/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/divxc3.c:31: undefined reference to `scalbnl'
/checkout/src/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/divxc3.c:33: undefined reference to `scalbnl'
```

What is the best way to solve it?
Is it to just rewrite the few functions needed or should I compile and link the copiler-rt project manually?

Is there a way to force the rust copiler to include all dependencies in the object file?